# Difference between VBProject unlocked and VBProject not protected

Tags: vba, excel, password-protection

I want to run code in the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event to lock a project when it is unprotected. But when I test the protection state it shows `vbext_pp_none` when I have been editing the code.

This question is not about "How to protect it"! That I have already covered.

Now the code below shows True when the project is protected but unlocked for editing:

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.VBProject.Protection = vbext_pp_none
```

I want to see the difference between:

- A project that is locked but the password entered for editing
- A project that is not protected.

Comment: The `VBProject.Protection` gives the actual state of the protection (at the moment of testing). So if it is usually protected but you entered the password for editing then its **actual state** is "*unprotected*" because obviously you opened it by entering the password. So as far as I know there is no possibility to distinguish between "*usually protected but user entered password*" and "*unprotected*" because both times the actual state is unprotected.

Comment: "No possibility to...", I was afraid someone was going to answer that.  Is there a way to undo the "login" possibly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the login is valid until you close and re-open the entire workbook, but I let me proof wrong. May I ask why you need that? Probably you are up the wrong tree and there is a workaround to achieve what you want?